# Spring configuration without XML is this reality?

Tags: java, spring

We're doing a website for [Cardshifter](https://github.com/Cardshifter/Cardshifter), and now I've converted the plain html files and css into a Spring MVC web application. Here is the typical configuration classes that I used in most of the project I work with.

```
package com.cardshifter.io.web.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.cardshifter.io.web" })
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setOrder(10);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setViewNames(new String[] { "*" });
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/css/**","/images/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/css/", "/images/");
    }

}
```

This is the class that define the view engines and a bunch of other stuff.

```
package com.cardshifter.io.web.config;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener;

import com.cardshifter.io.web.config.ApplicationConfig;

public class AppInitializer  implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(ApplicationConfig.class);

        // pour log4j
        servletContext.addListener(new Log4jConfigListener());

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        Dynamic dispatcherSpring = servletContext.addServlet("io", new DispatcherServlet(
                rootContext));
        dispatcherSpring.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcherSpring.addMapping("/");

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }

}
```

That class is the one responsible to expose the application to the servlet without a good old `web.xml`.

What I'm wondering is, is there something more I would need to add in order to make the configuration easier? I always have difficulty to set the resources (css, js, etc.) in the webapp, is what I'm doing the "right" way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely want to look into Spring Boot. It can significantly reduce Spring configuration + has a lot of features that help to with deployment to production. Think about it as "convention over configuration" wrapper for Spring framework.

If you would follow **Spring Boot conventions**, you may need to **shift some resources** to different folders, but I believe you would be able to **eliminate your spring configuration rapidly/completely.**

*If you decide not to use Spring Boot:*

You may want to use AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer instead of WebApplicationInitializer, because I don't observe any unusual servet configuration. It may look like this:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{ApplicationConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```